# The function $k \rightarrow \int_0^\pi \exp(k\sin x) dx$

Tags: real-analysis

From the analysis of an electronic circuit, I came up to the following function:

$k \rightarrow \int_0^\pi \exp(k\sin x) dx$

(k is the variable, x is a dummy integration variable). As far as I know, it is not possible to integrate in closed form. Any idea on its behaviour (as a function of $k$)?

Comment: Always check [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E(k*sin+x)+dx+from+x%3D0+to+pi) for these kinds of things

Comment: [Check some of these forms.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that this is not an elementary function.  But
Maple says
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}\!{{\rm e}^{k\sin \left( x \right) }}\,{\rm d}x=\pi\,{
{I}_{0}\left(k\right)}+\pi\,{{\rm \bf L}_{0}\left(k\right)}
$$
where $I_0$ is a [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1) and $\mathbf L_0$ is a [Struve L_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function).

Here is a graph

[image: graph]

Also
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}\!{{\rm e}^{k\sin \left( x \right) }}\,{\rm d}x \sim
\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}e^k}{\sqrt{k}}\quad\text{as }k \to +\infty
\\
\int_{0}^{\pi}\!{{\rm e}^{k\sin \left( x \right) }}\,{\rm d}x \sim
\frac{-2}{k}\quad\text{as }k \to -\infty
$$